# How can I find meeting point between of two google map routes in Android Studio using Java

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have **Lat,Long** of *Starting Point* and *Ending Point* of Route A and at the same time I have **Lat,Long** of *Starting* and *Ending Point* of Route B. Now I wan to find out if there is some way to find the meeting point of both routes in Android Studio in Java?